# Legend not displaying in plot function: R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have tried to plot a simple graph using the following code;

```
plot(y = Et, x = t, type = "l", col = 1,
 xlab = "Time",     ylab= "Equity ($)",
 main = "Figure 1–3: Randomly Generated Equity Curves") 
grid()
abline(h = 10000)
lines(y = Et2, x = t, col = 2)
lines(y = Eb, x = t, col = 8)
```

[image]

Then I try to add a legend to the plot

```
legend(x = "topleft", col = c(1,2,8), lwd = 2, legend = c("Curve 1",
                                                      "Curve 2",
                                                      "SPY"))
```

And the result I obtain is the following;

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT 1: I restarted R studio and re-ran the plots and got the following result.

[image]

EDIT 2: Reproducible code:

```
library(quantmod)
options("getSymbols.warning4.0" = FALSE,
        "getSymbols.auto.assign" = FALSE)

SPY <- getSymbols(c("SPY"), from = "2016-09-01")
SPY <- as.numeric(SPY$SPY.Close)

set.seed(123)

#create a time index
t <- 1:(length(SPY)-1)

#tradable capital vector
Vt <- c(rep(10000, length(t)))

#Benchmark return series
Rb <- rep(NA, length(t))
for(i in 2:length(t)) {
  Rb[i] <- (SPY[i] / SPY[i - 1]) - 1
}

#Benchmark equity curve
Eb <- rep(NA, length(t))
Eb[1] <- Vt[1]
for(i in 2:length(t)) {
  Eb[i] <- Eb[i - 1] * (1 + Rb[i])
}

#Randomy simulated return series 1
Rt <- rep(NA, length(t))
for(i in 2:length(t)) {
  Rt[i] <- Rb[i] + rnorm(n = 1,
  mean = 0.24/length(t),
  sd = 2.5 * sd(Rb, na.rm = TRUE))
  }


#Randomly simulated return series 2
Rt2 <- rep(NA, length(t))
for(i in 2:length(t)) {
  Rt2[i] <- Rb[i] + rnorm(n = 1,
                          mean = 0.02/length(t),
                          sd = 0.75 * sd(Rb, na.rm = TRUE))
}

# Randomly Simulated Equity Curve 1
Et <- rep(NA, length(t))
Et <- Vt[1]
for(i in 2:length(t)) {
  Et[i] <- Et[i-1] * (1 + Rt[i])
}

# Randomly Simulated Equity Curve 2
Et2 <- rep(NA, length(t))
Et2 <- Vt[1]
for(i in 2:length(t)) {
  Et2[i] <- Et2[i-1] * (1 + Rt2[i])
  }

#Plot of Et1 against the SPY Portfolio

plot(y = Et, x = t, type = "l", col = 1,
     xlab = "Time",     ylab= "Equity ($)",
     main = "Figure 1-3: Randomly Generated Equity Curves") 
grid()
abline(h = 10000)
lines(y = Et2, x = t, col = 2)
lines(y = Eb, x = t, col = 8)
legend(x = "topleft", col = c(1,2,8), lwd = 2, legend = c("Curve 1",
                                                          "Curve 2",
                                                          "SPY"))
```

The above code is what I have ran in order to produce the graphs above. If you are able to run it and get the same error let me know.

Comment: Should work as this plots fine `plot(1:10);legend(x = "topleft", col = c(1,2,8), lwd = 2, legend = c("Curve 1",
                                                                     "Curve 2",
                                                                     "SPY"))`

Comment: I just ran this and I am getting the same problem. However I did restart R studio and I encuntered a new problem.

Comment: then, you have to add some reproducible data. Otherwise it is not possible to help you.

Comment: Sure, I am using the quantmod package to play around with financial data.
EDIT: Code is too long for comments, please see the original post.

Comment: Please include some reproducible data, otherwise it is not possible to help you.

Comment: @user113156 your code works for me, the legend is right where it should be.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up